# Flutter Credit/Debit Card Scanner

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Having issues capturing credit card information with the following flutter packages,

https://pub.dev/packages/card_scanner

https://pub.dev/packages/credit_card_scanner

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_card_scanner_latest

As I am attempting to capture the card's information with my camera, however, it seems the tensorflow model(s) that the packages use are not performing well with letters/numbers that are non white.

For example, my Wells Fargo card has a red background and white letters/numbers and the reader works excellently. However, my Chase card has blue letters and and a blue background and does not work so well. Same with American Express as the letters are black/dark grey and the reader does not work so well. Does anyone have any alternative ideas? I know Airbnb's card reader uses some sort of different detector just for reference. Not sure if anyone in the flutter community is working on this.

Thank you